# Which Constructor to use? and Why? What is super used for?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, super

Code Sample #1 (Is my interpretation correct for these codes)

```
class Weather extends Equatable {
  final String cityName;
  final double temperature;

  Weather({
    @required this.cityName,
    @required this.temperature,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [cityName, temperature];
}
```

Code Sample #2
(Here the code throws error for adding an 'overrride')

```
class Weather extends Equatable {
  final String cityName;
  final double temperature;

  Weather({
    @required this.cityName,
    @required this.temperature,
  }) : super([cityName, temperature]);
}
```

[image]
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Which error, which override? Show us the exact error and the exact code you got the error from.

Comment: Hi, add the errors/warnings screenshots. I am trying to create a model class,

Comment: Code sample #2 is wrong.  `super()` invokes the base class's constructor, but the [`Equatable`](https://pub.dev/documentation/equatable/latest/equatable/Equatable-class.html) class's constructor takes no arguments.  Code sample #1 looks correct and implements `Equatable`'s required `props` getter.  Did you get an error using code sample #1?

Comment: Code Sample #1 has no error and as you suggested I went with it. However, can you kindly explain 'super() invokes the base class's constructor'. I am new and really confused with this concept. Or you might suggest any reading material that covers this concept.

Comment: For Dart specifically, I recommend reading [the Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).  However, if you're unfamiliar with object-oriented concepts (such as what a "base" (aka "super") class is), you probably should find some introduction to object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is `super` used for?

The keyword `super` is used to call the base class constructor. When you have a base class, you *have* to call that constructor. By default, if you don't do it explicitly, the constructor with no parameters will be called. The most obvious instance of having to call the constructor explicitly is when the base class does not have an accessible constructor without parameters.

> Which Constructor to use? and Why?

You use *your* constructor. You explicitly call the `super` constructor if you *need to*. If you don't need to, the default call is fine.

> What's wrong here?

Not your question, but that's why you are here I guess. In your second example you are calling a constructor of your base class that simply does not exist or is not accessible for you. I don't know where you got the idea that might work. Maybe outdated documentation or tutorials? Wishful thinking? In general, with a base class that does define a constructor like that, it would work. Your base class does not, so it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution #2 is not the way to use `equatable`.
To use `equatable` only solution #1 is valid.